# How to select a tag throuth another tag using Jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
            <td>
                <ul>
                  <li name="item">1</li>
                  <li name='definition'>2</li>
                  <li>3</li>
                  <li>4</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>News Cate</td>
            <td><a>ADD</a></td>
```

I want to use Jquery to retrieve the text value enclosed in html tag 'li',with name attribute which are set to 'item' and 'definition',by clicking the 'a' link,here is my Jquery code

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("td ul li[name='item']").text();
});
```

So,where went wrong?I need to find the text contained in

```
<li name="item">1</li>
```

and must find it from the starting point of a tag,how can I do

Comment: Try this `$("a").click(function(){var text=$("li[name='item']",$(this).closest("tr")).text();})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent` method doesn't work that way. You can use the `parent` and `prevAll` methods:

```
$("td a").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).parent("td").prevAll().find('li[name=item]').text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89a35xpx/

You could also get the closest `tr` and then select the target element:

```
var text = $(this).closest("tr").find('li[name=item]').text();
```

Comment: This works thanks,but I still dont know why should use prevAll() before find().prevAll() is supposed to use in a way that it should be supplied with a HTML tag to assign a point where all the doms before this point should be returned,but here,prevAll() has no html tag assigned as param ,so,where is the starting point for Jquery to look for?

Comment: @user7031 You are welcome. The starting point for `prevAll` is a node which is returned by `.parent('td')`. It starts from there and returns all the previous siblings, since here only `td` elements exist I didn't pass a selector to it. After that you have a collection of `td` elements, so `find` will find the target elements from there afterwards.

Comment: I think parent("td") will return a collection of td,isn't this enough?I still confused,sorry

Comment: @user7031 No, `parent` only selects the _parent_ element of the _this_ element, it doesn't select the siblings of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
var item = $("li[name='item']", parent).text();
var definition = $("li[name='definition']", parent).text();
```